# std::bind member function within struct

Tags: c++, c++11, member-functions

I have a function `bar` that is widely applicable, and not a member of any `struct`.
`bar` takes a functional/function pointer and some other arguments.

I also have many structs. They are heterogeneous in member variables.

Within each struct `Foo`, I want a member function of `Foo` to call on `bar` such that the functional supplied to `bar` is another non-static member function of `Foo`.

The many posts on SO related to `std::bind` with member functions but they seem slightly different.

```
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

typedef  vector<int>  V;

V bar(function<int(V)> f , V a) {
  // do work.
}

struct Foo
{
    V x;

    int f1(V y , int z) {
       // do work that involves member variable x,
       // and inputs y, z.
    }

    int f2() {
        std::function<V(int)> wrapper = std::bind(f1 , _1 , 7);
        V a;
        V c = bar(wrapper , a);
        return accumulate(c.begin(),c.end(),0);
    }
};
```

The error is of course:

> : error: invalid use of non-static member function

Comment: You're passing a `std::function<int(int)>` to a function that expects `std::function<int(std::vector<int>)>`. How can that work? I don't really follow your code.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings that was a typo. sorry. corrected.

Comment: Now you're passing a `std::function<std::vector<int>(int)>` to a function that expects `std::function<int(std::vector<int>)>`. I remain confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first (hidden) argument of a argument of a member function is the `this` variable. So the correct way to use `std::bind` here is

```
std::function<int(int)> wrapper = std::bind(&Foo::f1, this, _1 , 7);
```

However, modern C++, the correct way to do this is to use a lambda. I usually use explicit binds for this, so:

```
auto wrapper = [this](V v) {
  return f1(v, 7);
}
```

Comment: _"So the correct way to use std::bind here is..."_ [It isn't though](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/59e0bbdcaf2210fd)

Comment: @IdeaHat but lambda's cannot capture anything. so if it wasn't `7` but another variable, it wouldn't work. I should have put that in the question.

Comment: @cmo: _"but lambda's cannot capture anything"_ Since when?

Answer (score 2):

In general, don't use `std::bind()`.  There are very few circumstances where a lambda won't replace it, and understanding how to use `std::bind()` to the point where you are never surprised is a large investment.

`std::bind()` was brought into the language from `boost` at the same time lambdas were, and it could handle a few corner cases that lambdas could not.  By today, those corner cases are gone.  It would not be added (especially in its current form) if proposed today.

Instead, learn how to use lambdas.  Lambdas are about as hard to fully master as `std::bind()`, but are more powerful and useful today.  So learn to use the better option.

```
int f2() {
  V a;
  V c = bar([&](V in){return f(v, 7);}, a);
  return accumulate(c.begin(),c.end(),0);
}
```

This particular pattern relies on `bar` not storing the `std::function` after the call.